Noise on monitor when connected to internet
Faint horizontal noise appears on my monitor screen and changes depending on the state of the DSL and Internet indicators of the nearby router (~20cm away from monitor).
When there is no internet the noise disappears. When connecting, the noise frequency and polarity change. When connected and there is internet access, noise becomes faint and "small". It is more apparent on gray or dark areas of the UI or image being sent.
My monitor is a 10 year old Philips Brilliance 190B connected to a HP PC with the internet router being right above the PC case and connected to it with an Ethernet cable.
This noise is not apparent in screenshots and may not be that visible on camera.

If you move the router further away, or change the location/position of the monitor, does the noise change or go away?

It turns out the problem is related to the PC's ethernet status, not necessarily the router, disconnecting the ethernet cable from my PC the noise disappears.

This is likely to be caused of at least one component in the setup being of lower grade or not connected to a common ground, i.e. the devices, cabling or connectors.
Connectors might be oxidized, cable kinked (destroying shielding) or something similar.
Not having a common ground, or AC phase not the same for one or more AC/DC converter, may also cause strange phenomena;
e.g. when measuring electronics with an oscilloscope this can get quite confusing already in very simple setups - usually the mystery clarifies when correct grounding is established.

Note: The problem may also be inside a device, especially frequent on old battered devices.

My power outlets don't have a ground pin, maybe a reason?

"when connected to internet" - hmm. Cannot tell without being present on location, with measuring device available. Possibly, but might just show up to be part of the problem, not the true source.

It Was the Cable
I found and older VGA cable, replaced it with the one used, and boom, problem fixed, the image looks sharper and cleaner now.
Light grays look yellowish now but that's a problem simple color calibration can fix.
